# Changing XY position of UI Elements / Objects

Tags: objective-c, coordinates, uitoolbar

I want to know why you are unable to change the XY position of some objects in objective-c? For example... I had a toolbar with the following code, but it ONLY works if I place it WITHIN a UIView and then set the same coordinates... Can anyone explain why?

Doesn't Work:

```
 UIToolbar *commentstoolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 44)];
 [self.view addSubview:commentstoolbar];
```

Does Work:

```
 UIToolbar *commentstoolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
 UIView *toolbarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 44)];

 [toolbarView addSubview:commentstoolbar];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbarView];
```

Comment: This seems unusual behaviour... is there any other code that might be affecting this?

Comment: I opened a brand new project with just this code, and I get the same results. I have to be doing something wrong considering nobody has any possible solutions for me...

Comment: Assuming you are in a ViewController, are you doing this on -init -viewDidLoad or -viewDidAppear: ? Also Are you using Interface builder for this View Controller?

Answer (score 1):

The UIToolbar conforms to the [UIBarPositioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIBarPositioning) protocol, which specifies:

> The UIBarPositioning protocol defines the ways that bars can be
>   positioned on iOS devices. **Bars can be positioned at the bottom of
>   their enclosing view, at the top of their enclosing view**, or at both
>   the top of their enclosing view and also the top of the screen.

So the way to solve place a Tool bar anywhere is to enclose it in a view, just as you are doing.